# Always show photos full-screen on iOS?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, photos, photos.app

In the Photos app on my iPod Touch, when I'm scrolling through photos, it always makes "up" = the orientation of the device, even if that doesn't match the orientation of the photo.  So half the time, the photo takes up only half the pixels on the screen, and the other half are just black, and I have to rotate the device, and it takes a couple seconds to realize this and rotate the display.

Is there any way to make iOS/Photos always show photos full-screen, even when that doesn't match the current orientation of the device?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no.

Sorry!

There may be some jailbreak hack for this issue that I am unaware of, but there is no way to accomplish what you are asking with Apple's iOS and the Photos app on the iPhone/iPod Touch.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the built-in Photo app.  Can/do third-party apps display photos from the same library/database that Apple's app uses?

Comment: Yah any third party app can access your photos library. But the problem you are trying to solve is such a niche issue that I highly doubt you are even going to find a jailbreak app that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried was to rotate all the landscape pictures in portrait mode so they use all the screen.
The issue is that you then have to rotate your head as rotating the iPod will rotate the picture and you start again the same problem! :) Not very convenient then.

You have to find an application which will deactivate the automatic screen rotation and this should then work. It needs extra work upfront though.
As you already figured out, the best way would be to find a 3rd party application doing this automatically but, as Alex said, I'm quite doubtful it exists at the moment. Take some time to wander through the AppStore, who knows!